# Как вручную установить пакеты в Unity?

Tags: unity3d, package, shader-graph

У меня Unity 2017. Возможности обновить нет. Мне нужен Shader Graph, но его нет в моей версии и Packages Manager тоже нет. Я скачал Shader Graph с GitHub и скинул папки в проект. В консоли куча ошибок.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как от них избавится или сделать правильно?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `Сделать правильно` это следовать техническим требованиям. **Requires Unity 2018.1 Beta** (v1.1)

Comment: На версии 2017 добавить функции из 2018 практически невозможно. Не только в папках находятся изменения, нужно обновить сам Unity. А лучше, чтоб потом проект не разорвал на части, скачивайте сразу новую версию.